# Can't find copy if newer button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sfml.net

I am learning how to use SFML.NET with Microsoft visual Studio 2014 with C# and I added the C# dll's found in the lib folder using add existing files on My solution.

I cannot however, find the `copy if newer` button in the dll's property anywhere.

All the dll's say in there properties is the following:

```
(name)
Date created
Date modified
File Path
File size 
Read only
```

Comment: that property is in the reference properties.

Answer (score 2):

Use the context (right click) menu on the DLLs in Solution Explorer, select "Properties". The "Copy to output directory" field of the properties panel includes a "Copy if newer" value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net core, you can manually edit the .csproj file, and add something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="FileIWantToCopy.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```