# Can IIS operate SQLite with different System.Data.SQLite versions for different sites on one VPS when using Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite

I am using Asp.net to interact with an SQLite database using `System.Data.SQLite` in Visual Studio 2019. I installed the SQLite support package via NuGet in Visual Studio 2019, and you can see the installed packages in Image 1.

Project A utilizes `System.Data.SQLite` with version **1.0.117** to operate the SQLite database, and it works well after I upload the project A to a Windows 2016 server with IIS.

However, Project B uses `System.Data.SQLite` with version **1.0.118** to operate the SQLite database. While it works well on the local server, I encounter the following error after uploading Project B to the same Windows 2016 server with IIS:

*Server Error in '/' Application.
Unable to find an entry point named 'SI606edd9d386f5df5' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SI606edd9d386f5df5' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.*

Why is this happening?

By the way, Project B on the remote Windows 2016 server with IIS works well after I delete Project A on the same remote Windows 2016 server. It seems that IIS cannot load different `System.Data.SQLite` versions for different sites, is that correct?

**Image 1**
[image]

Comment: There are two versions of SQLite.Interop.dll, x64 and x86. No matter which one you are using, you will need to set its dll's "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy if newer" before deploying. You can try it to see if it can solve your issue

Comment: Thanks! Where can I set its dll's "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy if newer" before deploying in Vs 2019 ?

Comment: You need to right-click SQLite.Interop.dll in Explorer Solution, then find "Copy to output directory" in the properties window and change it to "Copy if newer".

Comment: Thanks! I can't find the item "Copy to output directory", you can check it in  both  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8uib6ejlyjzgal56cchgr/Publish.PNG?rlkey=tcsmgbagqstdl8g716naz3vxj&dl=0
and 
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zcoi3ae66f7z50ffuezww/Properts.PNG?rlkey=2x69a1alyqixqtij3igj7pmvq&dl=0

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks for the screenshot. You should change it in the properties of SQLite.Interop.dll under the x64 and x86 folders (required for both SQLite.Interop.dll). See if it works. If you have any issues I will be happy to share my experience with you

Comment: Thanks! I can't find  "Copy if newer" in the properties of SQLite.Interop.dll under the x64 and x86 folders , you can see the image https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2njr4dilsqjy773zzvfn2/newPublish.png?rlkey=7ltq2ukb7401plwmdxdxfcclj&dl=0

Comment: It is in my properties. I found this link for you. You can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054319/cant-find-copy-if-newer-button